# 'fabs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function when using templates

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
T* tContainer_t<T, R>::Remove( T item )
{    
    typename R::const_iterator it = std::find_if(Container.begin(), Container.end(),  [item](const T* v) { return std::fabs(*v - item) < DBL_EPSILON; });
    if (it != Container.end())
    {
        ...
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

`T` can be `int`, `double`, `float`, etc....

The compiler gives me `'fabs' : ambiguous call to overloaded function when using templates`

What's the problem and how can it be solved ?

Thanks.

Comment: What template type is it complaining about?

Comment: @rubenvb `<vector<double*> >` or `<list<int*> >` not sure, since the compiler doesn't say explicitly

Comment: You should just use `auto it`, it's more concise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `T` can be `int`, double, `float`, etc.

There are three overloads of `std::fabs` in C++ for `float`, `double`, and `long double`.

If you try to call `std::fabs` with an argument of type `int`, you will get a compilation error due to an overload ambiguity.  An `int` argument matches all three of the available overloads equally.

You could cast the argument to a known type (e.g. `double` or `long double`), which would resolve the ambiguity, or you could wrap the call to `fabs` in a template that performs disambiguation for integer-type arguments.

Alternatively, C++ has `std::abs`, which is overloaded for both integer and floating point types (declared in `<cmath>` and `<cstdlib>`).  Further, if you have a recent Standard Library implementation that implements C++11, a call to `std::fabs` with an integer type argument will automatically convert the argument to type `double`, so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: when using `std::abs` i get `conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal`

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Well, I'll take the spec over a wiki anyday.  The wiki also says `std::abs` doesn't have overloads for floats.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Nevermind, you were right.  26.8/11 specifies extra overloads without including the complete list of functions being overloaded for integer types.

Comment: @MooingDuck I was about to say, this compiles clean in gcc-4.8.  That raises the question though: poster is using lambdas so he *must* be using C++11.

Comment: @Michael What compiler and version?

Comment: @Michael:  Well, which expression does it say is of type `void`?  Which line of code does it point to when it says that?

Comment: @emsr I'm using VS2011 beta, which compiles comes with it ?

Comment: @emsr:  In reply to "must be using C++11," note that that "using C++11" is a very nebulous thing, since no compiler yet implements all of C++11 and all implementations are buggy.

Comment: @Michael: Your lambda has no effect, it just evaluates an expression and does nothing. You need to return the result of the comparison.

Comment: @Michael:  If you are using Visual C++, then you should get much more information from the compiler:  look in the Output window, not the Error List.  The Error List only lists the first line of every diagnostic message.  The Output window will have the complete error text, including all of the details.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis i've pasted the compiler output here : http://pastebin.com/5eZUY4Y3

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Understood on the C++ nebulosity.  OTOH, I would expect library support for abs and fabs to be pretty good no matter where you went.  Assuming that's the real problem.

Comment: @GManNickG you're right! i forgot to return, DOH! i edited the question since it's not relevant to my question

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Unfortunately, although this solution (to use `abs`) works almost everywhere, the current OSX version of Clang (based on LLVM 3.5) reports _another_ ambiguous error for `abs`....still looking for a solution for this.