# int abs(int) vs double abs(double)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, cmath

I'd like to understand the behavior of [the following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oZ58rbphIgf34OmZ), from the C++ Standard point of view (GCC 9.3, C++20):

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<class> struct type_tester;
int main() {
    type_tester<decltype(abs(0.1))>{};      // int abs(int) overload is selected for some reason!
    type_tester<decltype(std::abs(0.1))> {}; // double abs(double) overload is selected, as one would expect
}
```

So, `int abs(int)` is imported to the global namespace, while `double abs(double)` is not!

Why?

Comment: This is almost certainly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374037/ambiguous-overload-call-to-absdouble

Comment: Since this is from a c standard library I always mindlessly use `std::fabs` for doubles, I didn't know that `<cmath>` introduced overloaded functions.

Comment: `C` do not have overloads, so when you call `abs` from global namespace you're calling `C` function with `int` argument. When you using `std::` namespace then you use C++ where overload is available and there is `std::abs(double)`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/1jvY6z1vz

Comment: @AndrewHenle that's another question. And the answers there state that "the C++ header just includes that and pulls everything into namespace std"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, int abs(int) is imported to the global namespace,
>
> Why?

Because the C++ standard allows it to be imported into the global namespace.

> While double abs(double) is not!
>
> Why?

Because the C++ standard doesn't require it to be imported into the global namespace.

---

Relevant standard quotes:

> [headers]
>
> Except as noted in [library] through [thread] and [depr], the contents of each header cname is the same as that of the corresponding header name.h as specified in the C standard library.
> In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope of the namespace std.
> It is unspecified whether these names (including any overloads added in [support] through [thread] and [depr]) are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace std by explicit using-declarations ([namespace.udecl]).

---

Evidently, the C++ standard library implementation that you use had chosen to use the strategy described in the last paragraph of the quoted rule for the C standard library function, while having chosen not to use that strategy for the C++ standard library overloads. This specific outcome isn't guaranteed by the standard but it is conforming.

Another possible outcome would be that `abs(0.1)` would fail as use of an undeclared identifier. You cannot rely on C++ standard library names to be declared in the global namespace (unless you use the deprecated `<name.h>` C standard headers).

Answer (score 6):

`cstdlib` is the C++ version of the C header `stdlib.h`. Such headers must introduce the names in the `std` namespace and they are allowed to introcude them in the global namespace. There is no `double abs(double)` in the C header, hence there is no reason to introduce it in the global namespace like it is done for the C variants of the funciton. Note that C has no namespaces, and having the function in the global namespace helps for compatibility with C code. For `double abs(double)` this is not an issue, because the function does not exist in the C header.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header):

> For some of the C standard library headers of the form xxx.h, the C++
> standard library both includes an identically-named header and another
> header of the form cxxx (all meaningful cxxx headers are listed
> above). The intended use of headers of form xxx.h is for
> interoperability only. It is possible that C++ source files need to
> include one of these headers in order to be valid ISO C. Source files
> that are not intended to also be valid ISO C should not use any of the
> C headers.
>
> With the exception of complex.h , each xxx.h header included in the
> C++ standard library places in the global namespace each name that the
> corresponding cxxx header would have placed in the std namespace.
>
> These headers are allowed to also declare the same names in the std
> namespace, and the corresponding cxxx headers are allowed to also
> declare the same names in the global namespace: including `<cstdlib>`
> definitely provides std::malloc and may also provide ::malloc.
> Including `<stdlib.h>` definitely provides ::malloc and may also provide
> std::malloc. This applies even to functions and function overloads
> that are not part of C standard library.

*This applies even to functions and function overloads that are not part of C standard library*. That means: It would be allowed to have `double abs(double)` in the global namespace too, but it is not required.

Comment: So `cstdlib` puts *some* overloads to the global namespace just for C compatibility?

Comment: @IgorR. Yes. I added the relevant paragraph from cppreference. I guess very similar wording can be found in the standard

Comment: @IgorR. More like, `cstdlib` puts some allowed overloads in the global namespace for whatever is convenient for the authors that need to maintain both C and C++ standard libraries.