# Global namespace abs-function with double argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, cmath

While porting a program from Visual Studio to GCC, I bumped in a discrepancy in behavior related to global namespace `abs` function (not `std::abs`), which after code minimization can be shown in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << abs( -0.5 );
}
```

Here Visual Studio prints `0.5`, but GCC just `0`. It seems that only integer valued `abs` function is present in global namespace of GCC's `libstdc++`. Clang with `libc++` behaves like Visual Studio printing `0.5`. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EWbW5sf7c

Do MSVC and Clang extend the standard defining more functions in the global namespace than required?

P.S. I can find some old related questions, e.g. [Ambiguous overload call to abs(double)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374037/ambiguous-overload-call-to-absdouble), but the answer there speculates that the code as above `ought not to compile` at all.

Comment: `abs` is not provided in `<iostream>`.  Try changing `abs` to `std::abs`, and providing `#include <cmath>`.

Comment: @Eljay, thanks. `abs` is indirectly included via `<iostream>` in all implementations, adding `#include <cmath>` does not change anything in this example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yrac8rExd. I agree that using `std::abs` is the only safe way, but unfortunately there are large codebases that do use simple `abs` for floating-point arguments.

Comment: *Do MSVC and Clang extend the standard defining more functions in the global namespace than required?*  To answer your question: **no**, their defining more functions in the global namespace does not extend the standard.